# Overlay image over video stream using ffmpeg

Tags: shell, video, ffmpeg, webcam

I am trying to overlay an image over my webcam's video stream (`/dev/video0`) and send the output to another video stream (`/dev/video2`). So far, I have adapted a solution from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1108040/how-to-overlay-a-transparent-png-over-video-and-scale-to-video-size-in-ffmpeg?newreg=f786d8db0ccc400fa85066bafa1ee894) to overlay (and scale) an image over an existing video and stream it to the proper output.

```sh
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i video.mp4 -i image.png \
    -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]" \
    -map "[v]" -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

What can I use instead of `-stream_loop` to take the video from `/dev/video0` (a webcam) and overlay the same image on it in real time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing the `-stream_loop` parameter and specifying the format of the video stream using `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

```
ffmpeg -re -i /dev/video0 -i image.png -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]" \
    -map "[v]" -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

More refining from llogan's comment leads to the following final command:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -i image.png -filter_complex \
    "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p[v]" \
    -map "[v]" -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

Comment: `-re` shouldn't be used with live inputs. You can put the pixel format stuff into the filtergraph: `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -i image.png -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay=format=auto,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -f v4l2 /dev/video2`